How to efficiently query large datasets in GridDB with filtering and pagination?
I'm working with GridDB for storing and querying large datasets, and I'm trying to implement an efficient way to filter and paginate the data. Specifically, I need to:

Filter records based on specific criteria (e.g., range of timestamps or specific status codes).
Implement pagination to retrieve a limited number of records per request (e.g., 100 records per page).

Here is a simplified example of my current approach:
String query = "SELECT * FROM my_table WHERE status = ? AND timestamp BETWEEN ? AND ? LIMIT ? OFFSET ?";
PreparedStatement stmt = connection.prepareStatement(query);
stmt.setString(1, "active");
stmt.setTimestamp(2, startTime);
stmt.setTimestamp(3, endTime);
stmt.setInt(4, 100);  // Limit
stmt.setInt(5, offset); // Offset for pagination
ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery();

Any specific configuration or techniques to ensure indexes are used effectively during filtering and pagination?
